# Solve $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{\sin x- x \cos x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{\sin x - x \cos x}
$$
How can one go about solving this limit using real analysis? Would a definition from the calculus proportion of real analysis suffice in order to fully solve this question? What would the proper way of setting out a proof for this problem be? I have tried using the epsilon delta definition which has not worked.

Comment: If you know the proof of l'Hopital, you could try using that.

Comment: (Edited) Just a minor point, but you should put question marks at the end of your questions.

Comment: Thank you dylan. Sayatankhan could you apply the proof directly, as in can you do it in a real analysis instead of just doing the computation.

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Use that

- $\sin x=x-x^3/6 +o(x^3)$
- $\cos x=1-x^2/2 +o(x^2)$

then

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{\sin x - x \cos x}
=
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3+o(x^3)}{-x^3/6 +x^3/2+o(x^3) }
$$

Comment: So you use a O-symbolics approach instead of l'hopitles approach?

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn Those are the Taylor's expansion for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, a foundamental tools to solve more difficult limits. Note that in this case I've used little-o notation which means that $\sin x=x-x^3/6 +o(x^3)$ indication with $o(x^3)$ othe terms with exponent $>3$ and thus negligible for the calculation of the limit.

Comment: @AlexanderQuinn If you are not aware about Taylor's expansion then in this case you need to use l'Hopital a shown in other answers.

Comment: I see now I was just confused as to the notation being used

Comment: Maybe you use big-O notation? it is also good and doesn’t change so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use l'hospital's rule:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{\sin x - x \cos x} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x \sin x+x^2 \cos x}{\cos x - \cos x +x \sin x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2x \sin x+x^2 \cos x}{x \sin x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin x +2x \cos x  +2x \cos x -x^2 \sin x}{ \sin x +x \cos x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin x +4x \cos x -x^2 \sin x}{ \sin x +x \cos x}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\cos x +4 \cos x -4x \sin x -2x \sin x +x^2 \cos x}{ \cos x + \cos x-x \sin x}\\
&= \frac{2\cos 0 +4 \cos 0 -4\cdot0 \sin0 -2\cdot0 \sin 0 +0^2 \cos 0}{ \cos 0 + \cos 0-0 \sin 0}\\
&= \frac{2 +4  }{ 1 + 1}\\
&= \frac{6}{ 2}=3\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{\sin x - x \cos x}=&\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 \sin x}{\sin x - x \cos x}\cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin x}=\\
&\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3}{\sin x - x \cos x}\overbrace{=}^{L'H}\\
&\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3x^2}{x\sin x}=3.\end{align}$$